FastAPI add Tags to APIRouter
How do you look at such a solution?:
user_router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/user", tags=["users"]
)
user_router.tags_metadata = [
    {
        "name": "users",
        "description": "Operations with users. The **login** logic is also here.",
    }
]

I am extending the APIRouter class in this way. Then, when adding all routers, I will use the function and connect the tags.
def collect_openapi_tags(*routers):
    tags = []
    for router in routers:
        if hasattr(router, 'tags_metadata'):
            tags.extend(router.tags_metadata)
    return tags

app = FastAPI
app.openapi_tags = collect_openapi_tags(user_router)

It is frightening that the ApiRouter class does not imply the presence of the tags_metadata parameter. Does the approach have a place to be?
I was looking for similar solutions, but I didn't find them.
